# Printing multiple-page PDF file, using different trays

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, postscript

As part of my current project, I am creating an app in C# to generate multi-page invoices in PDF format. I also merge 100 invoices into a single PDF file using the PDFSharp library. However, I am having trouble printing invoices.

The first and second pages of each invoice should be printed on paper from the first tray, while any additional pages should be printed from the second tray.

Previously, we exported invoices as PostScript files, allowing us to easily define printer trays.

Regarding this issue, I have several questions.

- Can each page of a PDF file have a property to set the tray name/number?
- Is it necessary to convert the PDF to PostScript again in order to define the tray for each page? Is this a straightforward task if so?
- Should we create a separate application specifically for printing and set the tray page by page?

Any insights or experiences you may have in this area would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not having 2 separate pdf? merge page 1 and page 2 from all your pdf in P1.pdf and the remaining of the pages in P2.pdf. send P1.pdf to first tray and P2.pdf to second tray? BTW, does your printer has 2 tray or you are talking about 2 separate printers?

Comment: The reason I merged 100 invoices is that we send them out in batches. To answer your question, all invoices should be printed in the correct order on a single printer.